# sql query update table with missing fields from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have an issue with a SQL query/SP where I'm trying to update a table that has missing data in specific fields from another table where the data in those same fields exists and is valid.  The trick here is I would like to anchor on a value in the first table.  I can make it work with a `INSERT INTO` / `SELECT FROM` combo, but it creates a duplicate record.

Im using mysql 5.x.  Here are the details. The table with missing data is `thisweek` and the table with valid data is `lastweek`. Field 1 is `MACAddress` (which exists and is the anchor) and exists in both tables (for ex. BE:EF:BA:BE:CA:FE), Fields 2-10 in `thisweek` are blank (''), but there is data in those same fields(Fields2-10) in table `lastweek`.

```
UPDATE thisweek
SET thisweek.field2 = lastweek.field2
where thisweek.MACAddress = lastweek.MACAddress and thisweek.filed2 = '';
```

I know that query isn't anywhere close, so looking for help.  Again, the same `MACAddress` exists in both tables, with the only difference between tables being that field2 in `thisweek` is blank (and it shouldn't be) and needs to be equal to `lastweek.field2` for that `MACAddress`.

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to  JOIN thisweek and lastweek tables.

```
UPDATE thisweek
JOIN lastweek
ON thisweek.MACAddress = lastweek.MACAddress
AND thisweek.field2 =''
SET thisweek.field2 = lastweek.field2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
UPDATE tw 
  SET tw.Field2 = lw.Field2
FROM
  ThisWeek tw 
  JOIN LastWeek lw ON tw.MACAddress = lw.MACAddress
WHERE
  tw.Field2 = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id and (table1.name = '' or table1.name is null) 
set table1.name = table2.name;
```